# Python passing javascript to true/false

Tags: python, selenium, web, driver

So I am trying to create a python program that checks if an item is instock or out of stock. To do this I use the selenium chrome web driver. In order to check if an item is in stock, I use this code:

```
print(driver.execute_script("return document.body.innerText.includes('sold out')"))
```

I wish to use this in an if statement so I can make it run a Discord webhook if it comes back true/false.

```
if(driver.execute_script("return document.body.innerText.includes('sold out')" == 'False')):
```

The code without the if statement runs fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! Sorry.

test = (driver.execute_script("return document.body.innerText.includes('sold out')"))